# How to select the relative complement of a table B in a table A (A \ B) in an SQL-Query?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I've got two tables:

1. subjects:
   [id, ...]
2. categories:
   [subject.id, ...]

I want to select all subjects from table #1 without the entries in #2 (categories).

Any tips appreciated (:

best regards

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
select * from subjects where id not in (select subject.id from categories )
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Quite easy (:

Answer (score 32):

Sachin's already provided a correct answer, but you can do it with join syntax as well:

```
SELECT
  subjects.*
FROM
  subjects
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  categories
ON
  subjects.id = categories.subject_id
WHERE
  categories.subject_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that anyway. Sachins way looks much easier (maybe faster) but I've chosen your way, because Sachins suggestion made some trouble to implement via active record.

Comment: +1 for using join. Again a classic case of Join vs subquery ... :)

Comment: With MySQL, join syntax is almost always equal (because the planner rewrote the subquery as a join) or faster. The query planner is dumb and makes bad choices for index usage on subqueries far more often.

Comment: I test both queries and the one with the join is way faster, maybe the subquery can be improved adding some indexes